# python list ofwords.the program outputsthosewords&theirfrequencies.Ex:if the input is:hey hi Mark hi mark the output is: hey 1 hi 2 Mark 2 hi 2 mark 2

Tags: python, list

I thought I could use this code:

```
wordInput = input()

myList = wordInput.split(" ")

for i in myList:

   print(i,myList.count(i))
```

but its output is:

```
hey 1
Hi 1
Mark 1
hi 1
mark 1
```

How can I make it:

```
Hey 1
Hi 2
Mark 2
hi 2
mark 2
```

Comment: What is the input here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your strings to a homogeneous format, for example lowercase.

Also, the best is to first count the occurrences, then display (rather than searching and counting repeatedly).

```
wordInput = 'hey hi Mark hi mark'

words = wordInput.split()
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(map(str.lower, words))

for w in words:
    print(w, counts[w.lower()])
```

Output:

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 2
hi 2
mark 2
```

Alternative that avoid computing twice the lowercase (but requires to store a lowercase copy of the list):

```
wordInput = 'hey hi Mark hi mark'

words = wordInput.split()
words_lc = [w.lower() for w in words]
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(words_lc)

for w, w_lc in zip(words, words_lc):
    print(w, counts[w_lc])
```

Comment: @manduuk this is beginners code, all standard builtins and modules ;)

Comment: @mozway Sir mozway, would you recommend me something to get better in pandas and numpy?